# Does anybody know how to embed a live Periscope stream on their website?

Tags: node.js, twitter, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I want to know how to embed live periscope stream on my website.if anybody knows about live streaming please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a tweet that links to the periscope stream you would like ([periscope embedding documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/periscope)), and there are a variety of ways of embedding a tweet, as detailed in [twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets)

Comment: i want to embed a live video stream not  a tweet.is there any other way do achieve that?

Comment: @Karan I don't think so - I suppose you could try embedding a tweet and then hiding everything except the actual stream with CSS - that way you could also style it to fit with the rest of your website

Comment: thanks for your valuable replies.. but it is not a good programming manner. is n't?

Comment: It's not a great solution, but it's all I could find, unfortunately